# What does 'Braked Voltage' mean on a charge controller?

Tags: voltage, charger, generator

Here is the complete specs of the [controller](http://www.ebay.com/itm/291054739989?var=590219212750&ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649).

Battery rated voltage: 12v 
Wind turbine rated power: 300w 
**Wind turbine braked voltage: 15v** 
Recover voltage: 13.5v 
Quiescent dissipation: <8ma 
Pretection grade:IP67

Does the braked voltage imply protection for voltage spikes thus braking the wind mill by applying some type of shorted load? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Very sparse data on that controller... When the windmill generates a too high output the controller will apply the brake. This might be a dump resistance or some other smarter load that leaves power for the utility. It doesn't say on this particular controller how it is done. There is a hysteresis that releases the brake when the voltage reaches 13.5V.